# Binary Search (Java) exception on 5th element

Tags: java, binary-search

The method binarySearch returns ArrayOutOfBounds exception when I make an array of 5 elements and search for the 5th element. All other test cases are working fine up to 10 elements.

This error was encountered even if I used if-else loop. Anybody with an explanation and a solution?

```
    private static int[] arrayEntry() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");

        int size = scan.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter the items of the array: ");
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        return arr;
    }

        //code for choice menu

            case 2:
                Arrays.sort(arr);
                System.out.println("Enter the item to be searched: ");
                searchItem = scan.nextInt();
                int result = binarySearch(arr, searchItem);

                if (result!=-1){
                    System.out.println("Item found at index: "+ result+ " (index starting at 0).");
                }else System.out.println("Item not found!");

                break;

    private static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int searchItem) {

        int lastItem = arr.length-1;
        int startItem = 0;

        while(startItem<=lastItem){
            int midValue = startItem + (lastItem-1)/2;

            if (searchItem == arr[midValue]){
                return midValue;
            }

            if (searchItem>arr[midValue]){
                startItem = midValue+1;
            }else lastItem = midValue-1;
        }return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Share the stack trace please

Comment: Your midvalue calculation is wrong. It's trying to search for a number at array[5] when array goes from 0-4.

Comment: For sure there is an error with computation of "midValue", as it should be:

int midValue = (startItem + lastItem-1)/2;

Note that the entire expression is dived by two, not just lastItem.

This may, or may not be the only bug, but for sure this is the problem.

Comment: @Piotr, this solution gives "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError" but (startItem+lastItem)/2 worked for me.

Comment: @KumarShivam How? There is no recursion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public int runBinarySearchIteratively(
 int[] sortedArray, int key, int low, int high) {
 int index = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

 while (low <= high) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (sortedArray[mid] < key) {
        low = mid + 1;
    } else if (sortedArray[mid] > key) {
        high = mid - 1;
    } else if (sortedArray[mid] == key) {
        index = mid;
        break;
    }
}
return index;
}
```

Source: http://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-search

Comment: this did the job! Thanks